# Keep session with cURL in codeigniter php

Tags: php, session, curl, codeigniter-3

I have a external API where I want to GET some data, and I want to keep session id through all the request until I log out. Using cURL lib in codeigniter I have the following flow (myacc and mypass are just placeholders):

```
public function getCURL() {
   echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://37.99.110.537:6001/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=2&account=myacc&passwd=mypassD&format=sid&session=SurveillanceStation');
}
```

This will output:

```
{"data":{"sid":"lH6WJCWMm5rkA14B0MPN570354"},"success":true}
```

I will have to keep that provided sid (session id) when making the next request:

```
http://37.99.110.537:6001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera&method=GetSnapshot&version=1&cameraId=2&timestamp=1480512959&preview=true&_sid="lH6WJCWMm5rkA14B0MPN570354"
```

See at the end **sid="lH6WJCWMm5rkA14B0MPN570354"**.

And then log out and kill that sid.

After each login I would get a new sid that I have to use it to get a picture (with that URL) and then logout.

I think that saving and using cookies from a file in my case isn't needed, I think something like:

```
public function getCURL() {
   echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://37.99.210.237:6001/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=2&account=myacc&passwd=mypassD&format=sid&session=SurveillanceStation');

   if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $data= array(
                'sid'=> $this->input->post('sid'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);

if(false == $this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
       echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://37.99.110.537:6001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera&method=GetSnapshot&version=1&cameraId=2&timestamp=1480512959&preview=true&_sid="sid"');

}

}
}
```

^^ That syntax is messed up, but how I can make it in a proper way or how it's the best way to keep session id on the request chain ?

Comment: "I think that saving and using cookies" <- incorrect. CodeIgniter's sessions cannot work without cookies.

Comment: do you need that `sid` to append it to `url` or send it via cookie?

Comment: Just to append it to url.

Comment: Can You pls tell me you are using which library or source? I am having same issues ? I need Curl Library !

Comment: Hello @JayminsFakeAccount, I'm using : https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl you will only have download the lib and put it in your lib folder and you are ready to use it, if you have any issues let me know, I also found a good way to store the sid with the other cookies!

Comment: Okay ! Thanks mate! I got it from your source and used it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to keep `sid` for long session, for multiple request etc, you can save this `json` to some `json` file and clear content of file while logging out.

wrap your `$sid` getter to some other function.

```
function getSid()
{
    //try to read from json
    if(is_file('path/to/sid.json'){
        $sid = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/sid.json', true));
        if(!isset($sid['logout'])){
            return $sid['data']['sid'];
        }
    }
    $sid = $this->curl->simple_get('http://37.99.110.537:6001/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=2&account=myacc&passwd=mypassD&format=sid&session=SurveillanceStation');

    //check and save `$sid`

    if(strlen($sid) > 20) {
        file_put_contents('path/to/sid.json', $sid);
        return json_decode($sid, true)['data']['sid'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

and update content of `sid.json` while logging out.

```
function logout()
{
    file_put_contents('path/to/file', json_encode(['logout' => 'true']));
}
```

and call these methods.

for every request in one execution, it will use the same `sid`, and when you'll hit 'logout()' it will destroy the `sid` so that new generated and used on next execution.